# How to run a node Puppeteer app on Ubuntu Server as root

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, vps, puppeteer

I'm trying to run node apps that use the npm package Puppeteer to scrape websites, using VPSes that use root as the default user I login as.

It never works. I always have to spend half an hour googling to find the solution... well no more.

Comment: Flagging to close due to the low quality of the q&a (it's too unspecific).

Comment: @NinoŠkopac It's been here a while so I'd rather you didn't... I'm open to suggestion for how I can make it more specific.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Do this:

**0. Run `sudo apt update`**

**1. Install libx stuff**

```
sudo apt-get install libpangocairo-1.0-0 libx11-xcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxi6 libxtst6 libnss3 libcups2 libxss1 libxrandr2 libgconf-2-4 libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libgtk-3-0
```

**2. Set --no-sandbox argument in the launch() part of your Puppeteer app (only required if you are running as root/root's cron)**

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true, args: ['--no-sandbox']})
```

E: as Niko pointed out, `--no-sandbox` opens your server to a malicious attack from a website the scraper visits. It looks like there are some StackOverflow questions elsewhere that post alternatives that aren't awful to implement. I like David's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53681161/why-puppeteer-needs-no-sandbox-to-launch-chrome-in-cloud-functions) which seems to suggest that even in 2021 `--no-sandbox` is still a necessary evil in some cases.

E2: See answer below. It looks like in 2021 we also have to install `libgbm-dev`

Comment: past jspinella is the real mvp

Comment: make sure to run sudo apt update or you might get a package not found error like me

Comment: libgconf2-4 should be libgconf-2-4

Comment: `--no-sandbox` is very dangerous and should only be run on *trusted* websites.  -1

Comment: Can't argue with that

Answer (score 5):

**Connecting to the server by SSH:**

1. Open your terminal
2. Type: ssh root@[server ip]
3. If it is the first time you connect to the server you will get a security prompt. Type 'yes'
4. Fill in your password:  [password]
5. You should now be connected to your server

**Installing the app:**

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y libgbm-dev

sudo apt install -y gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget

sudo apt install curl

curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | sudo -E bash -

sudo apt install nodejs

sudo apt install git

git config --global user.name "your name"

git config --global user.email "your email"

git clone "your project git url"

cd "your project folder"

npm i

npm start

---

If you need to run multiple apps on one VPS server - google tool "Screen"

Answer (score 0):

After I installed libgbm,  everything works fine for me!
hope that help you out

```
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install -y libgbm-dev
```

Comment: It looks like `libgbm-dev` is a new dependency for Puppeteer. I'll add it to my answer so it's current. Did you have to install anything else e.g. what I installed above?