# Why Puppeteer needs --no-sandbox to launch Chrome in Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

When I run Puppeteer on Cloud Functions with Node 8, I get this error.

```
Error: Failed to launch chrome!
[1205/063825.588245:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(89)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.
```

Launching Puppeteer with

```
browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: ['--no-sandbox'],
    headless: true
})
```

solves the issue.
I have searched on the internet and could not find any reason why is this necessary?

Why does Headless Chrome run as root in the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As *Cloud Functions* is serverless you can do not much more than using this Chromium flag at launch each time.

### Background

The usage of `--no-sandbox` flag is only a workaround to make browser launch possible on Linux systems.

It is related to security, concretely: [Linux sandboxing](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/docs/linux/sandboxing.md) and it is advised to set up your own sandbox for Chromium if you are dealing with untrusted web traffic instead of using chrome without one.

You can set up a sendbox on Linux with [user namespace cloning](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/user_namespaces.7.html). In case of Cloud Functions I am not aware of any solutions if this could be set up: so you need the `no-sandbox`, but make sure your puppeteer scripts visiting only trusted pages.